# How to get all 'Full page Url' stats with Google Analytics Data API into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to fetch our statistics from GA4 on a daily basis into my Google Sheet with the Google Analytics Data API. However, it looks like, especially when we have a lot of traffic and visits on pages with unique parameters in it, that there is a lot of data that is not being imported by the system. Is there a limit on how many rows of data can be imported when you use 'fullPageUrl'?

When I compare the stats with the data in GA4 itself or in Looker Studio where I also connected GA4 the statistics are not the same.

Is there a trick to make sure that all the fullPageUrl stats are being imported? Or has it something to do with the script I'm using?

This is the script I am using:

```
// test both, reservation and step
function runReportReservationURLRooms() {
  const propertyId = '[propertyID]';
  const requiredDimensionValues = ['reservation', 'step=rooms'];

  try {
    const dimension = AnalyticsData.newDimension();
    dimension.name = 'fullPageUrl'; // Use fullPageUrl as the dimension

    const dateRange = AnalyticsData.newDateRange();
    dateRange.startDate = 'yesterday';
    dateRange.endDate = 'yesterday';
    const request = AnalyticsData.newRunReportRequest();
    request.dimensions = [dimension]; // Include only the dimension
    request.dateRanges = [dateRange];

    const metrics = [
      'screenPageViews',
            'sessions'
    ].map(metricName => {
      const metric = AnalyticsData.newMetric();
      metric.name = metricName;
      return metric;
    });
    request.metrics = metrics;
    const report = AnalyticsData.Properties.runReport(request, 'properties/' + propertyId);
    if (!report.rows) {
      console.log('No rows returned.');
      return;
    }
    
    // Filter URLs based on required dimension values using JavaScript filter method
    const filteredRows = report.rows.filter(row => {
      const url = row.dimensionValues[0].value; // Assuming fullPageUrl is the first dimension
      
      return requiredDimensionValues.every(value => url.includes(value));
    });

    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('GA4 reservation url rooms');
    if (!sheet) {
      spreadsheet.insertSheet('GA4 reservation url rooms');
    }
    // Append the headers.
    const dimensionHeaders = report.dimensionHeaders.map(dimensionHeader => dimensionHeader.name);
    const metricHeaders = report.metricHeaders.map(metricHeader => metricHeader.name);
    const headers = [...dimensionHeaders, ...metricHeaders];
    sheet.appendRow(headers);
    // Append the filtered results.
    const rows = filteredRows.map(row => {
      const dimensionValues = row.dimensionValues.map(dimensionValue => dimensionValue.value);
      const metricValues = row.metricValues.map(metricValue => metricValue.value);
      return [...dimensionValues, ...metricValues];
    });
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(rows);
    console.log('Report added to the spreadsheet.');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed with error: %s', e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question